# Where should i set a BOOL for a UIView animation?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to do a UIView animation like this

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin.y += 30.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
    view.frame = frame;
} completion^(BOOL finished){
     viewMovedDown = YES;
}];
```

Should I set the BOOL (viewMovedDown) in the completion block or should I set it in the beginning itself before doing the animation?

Comment: Either way, it gets set.  Pick and choose.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve here. Leave it where it is if you only want it to be set to true when the animation has completed. If you want it true for when the animation has initiated, put it in the first block.

Comment: The above code looks fine for me. Any specific issues you are facing?

Comment: It depends upon the purpose of the `BOOL`. If it's so you make sure you don't kick off a subsequent animation dependent upon the first one, then do it in the `completion` block. But if you just want to know that the animation was started or is progress, then do it outside of the `completion` block. Personally, unless I'm doing something that is strictly dependent upon the animation, I put it outside the `completion` block.